# How to parse JSON in on response

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am using volley and implementing json parsing. I am doing json parsing and showing the data in the list view. I had made every thing ( getter setter,singleton class, adapter etc) but at the time of parsing i am facing difficulty, how to parse

```
{
"result": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Prabhat",
    "email": "prabhat@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Apurva",
    "email": "apu@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "sunny",
    "email": "sunny@mail.com"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Creation InfoTech",
    "email": "creation@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Sanjay Mishra",
    "email": "sanju19@gmail.com"
}]
```

}

> And my java code is

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url_Array, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "working");
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Now this is my PersonInfo class in which i have define my getters and setters
                    PersonInfo info = new PersonInfo(object.getString("id"), object.getString("name"), object.getString("email"));
                    personInfos.add(info);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
    AppController.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).AddtoRequestQueue(request);

}
```

**Facing difficulty in parsing,kindly reply **

Comment: "Facing difficulty in parsing". What are we supposed to make of this? What does that mean? Are you getting errors?

Comment: yes, i am facing error in on response.

Comment: what errors you get, or what result you want to get?

Comment: just create proper models and use Gson lib for deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Before walking the list, you need first to get the `JSONArray`:

`JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("result")`

Then you walk the array:

`for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help you to read your data into two string arrays then you can do whatever you want with them

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url_Array, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("result");
        String[] name=new String[jsonArray.length()];
        String[] email=new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "working");
                    JSONObject student=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    name[i]=student.getString("name");
                    email[i]=student.getString("email");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something not ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });    AppController.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).AddtoRequestQueue(request);

}
```

Comment: it is showing the data only in the first row of the list view, remaining data (4 rows) is not showing